# Use system command to download XML file

Tags: windows, shell, system, command-prompt

I am writting expansion programs to a CAD program called 12d Model. The language I write these expansions in is simply called Macro language and it has a very limited API. So it doesn't have a way to find a file on Windows, list all files in a directory or download a file.

To overcome this I use simple ShellExecute and system calls. For example to list all files in a directory I use the system call "dir C:\ /B > C:\MyCurrentFolder\outfile.txt". One of my needs is to download and parse an XML file but the API has no download function.

**Is there a system call to download a file from a URL?** Is there some native way to do this? Maybe there is a Windows Application like regedit.exe or something that I can use to download a file?

If not, do you think it would be possible to do it through a batch script?

Comment: Can you install [wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)? I am guessing your expansion program will be distributed to computers which you cannot control the environment, so this is probably not an option.

Comment: @AaronWilliams Not really. Unless I bundle the wget.exe inside the macro code then copy/write it to the users computer. That will make the macro large and I'll have to prompt the user if I can install a program on their computer. Its an option but a native way would be easier if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Windows does have built in FTP support using `ftp.exe`. So if you could find a FTP mirror of the file, or upload it to one yourself, that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a native way to do this.  Use the msxsl.exe parser to download the xml file and save it to whatever location you would like.  You can do this from the command prompt or from a batch file.  Note the one caveat to this is you will need to use an xsl file that does not alter the xml file.  The command would look something like this...

c:\msxsl.exe c:\myXML.xml c:\myXSLT.xsl > c:\myXML.xml

Note here the file located at c:\myXSLT.xsl cannot change the source file c:\myXML.xml